# Using pointers to iterate over strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a string

```
char *str = "hello world";
```

I also have a int pointer

```
int *ptr;
```

How can I use these two in a function that loops over the string and prints all the chars in it?
The header function would be something like this:

```
void print(const int *ptr){
    while(*ptr != 0){
        printf("%c", (char)*ptr);
        ++ptr;
    }
}
```

Now I know that I want to use the ptr to somehow reference the char ptr. But how would I do this?
I've tried doing just

```
ptr = str;
```

And tried a whole bunch of different combinations of

```
ptr=*str;
ptr=&str;
```

And so on.

I know I can iterate over the string just doing

```
while(*str != 0){
    printf("%c",*str)
    str++;
}
```

And that I can also do it using index elements like str[0].
But how can I use a pointer to act as the index element for the char string?

Comment: The problem might just be that your pointer is a pointer to `int`? That means when you increment it, it will point to the next int in memory - and an int is bigger than a char. Why are you using an int pointer anyway?

Comment: Why don't you use a pointer to `char` (`char*`) instead of a pointer to `int` (`int*`)?

Comment: @sje397 I thought that because the header for the print function takes an int as a parameter I had to use the and int pointer before it to reference the string? Is this unnecessary?

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 The print function you've provided seems broken...where is it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use `int *` to access `char *`? It is not correct and shouldn't be done so.

The main problem with it is that each time you increase you pointer `ptr` by `1` it is incremented by `sizeof(int)` bytes (which is platform dependent and varies between 2 and 4). While each character in the string is of size 1 byte.
Also when you write `*ptr` you actually access `sizeof(int)` bytes which may result in segmentation fault if `ptr` points to the end part of the string.

If you have no option to change the function signature do it like this:

```
void print(const int *ptr){
    const char* char_ptr = (const char*)ptr;

    while(*char_ptr != 0){
        printf("%c", *char_ptr);
        ++char_ptr;
    }
}
```

If all you need is just to print the string to which (for some reason) `const int* ptr` is pointing then you can do something like that:

```
void print(const int *ptr)
{
    printf("%s", ptr);
}
```

`printf` won't check the type of the pointer, it will assume that the pointer is pointing to a buffer of `char`s and will print the whole buffer until it reachs `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you Alex.
Yes a problem is that I can't change the signature for the function.
If I can't change anything inside the function either, but I have to define everything outside. Would I still define the `char ptr` the same way you've show?

Because I would just like to call `print(char ptr)` and have it print the results.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 Oh, I see, so you have this function `void print(const int *ptr)` and you know that the pointer is pointing to the string and you want to print that string? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Lop Kind of. I have that function yes, and I also have the `char *str = "Hello World"`. But I'm not sure how to go about linking these two with each other. How would I go about being able to call `print(*str)` and it will iterate over the `char *str = "Hello World"`? Because just calling the `print` function with `print(*str)` doesn't work since `print`expects a `const int *ptr` parameter.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 You can call it `print((const int*)str);` but if the implementation of `print` function that you posted is the one which going to be executed then it won't work as you expect... For explanation why, see the beginning of my answer. (**NOTE** that casting `char*` to `int*` is very dangerous and may lead to undefined behavior, thus not recommended. Use it only if you know and understand what you are doing)